# XNA How to display what is underneath the game window?

Tags: c#, xna

What I would like to do is to simply display a `Texture2D` on the screen, the screen needs to be transparent as well. I already have a section of code I found which can make the window borderless.

```
IntPtr hWnd = this.Window.Handle;
var control = System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromHandle(hWnd);
var form = control.FindForm();
form.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
```

When put into the `Initialize()` method, this successfully makes the window borderless.

however, when I use a `GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);` in my `Draw` all it results in is a black square in the middle of my screen.

Is there a way to change the opacity of the background at all? Is there anything else I can try to fix this?

Some things I heard of were to take a screenshot of the background and display it on the screen via backbuffer, however I can't find any solutions that successfully implement that.

**EDIT:** Here is the draw method, while rather simple

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        {

            spriteBatch.Draw(tex, parameters, Color.White );

        }
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

I also found I can change the forms opacity via `form.opacity = 0;` but that makes the texture transparent as well.

Comment: Problem may be in your draw method but we can't see it.

Comment: Your base.Draw is outside of the spritebatch. Begin. You should also post that code and make sure it is in a spritebatch.begin.  Also if I remember correctly you can change the opacity in the spritebatch.draw.

Comment: That is not my issue, I would like to make the background (in this case, the `BackColor` referenced in Winforms to be transparent. If I were to change the Color in the draw method, it would just change the textures color (referenced by `tex`)